# Execute decrypt function on LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, sqlclr

If I have the following query where `Companies.Name` is encrypted:

Obviously executing the following query is going to be invalid because we're searching against encrypted names.

```
IQueryable<File> files = GetFiles(f => f.Clients.Any(fc => fc.Contacts.Any(c => c.Companies.Any(x => x.Name.Contains(searchText)))));
```

I'm after a way to decrypt `Companies.Name` before the query is executed via a `Decrypt()` function we already have in place.

**EDIT 1:**

I do have a partial class `Company` with a decrypted property called `DisplayName` that returns the decrypted `Name` property, however LINQ is telling me the specified type member `DisplayName` is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

```
IQueryable<File> files = GetFiles(f => f.Clients.Any(fc => fc.Contacts.Any(c => c.Companies.Any(x => x.DisplayName.Contains(searchText)))));
```

If there's a way to use a partial class property inside a LINQ statement I guess it would work.

**EDIT 2:**

I ended up creating a SQL CLR function that decrypts the company names and I can now call `dataContext.SearchCompanies(searchText)` in code to return a list of `Companies`.

I'm not sure however, how to easily replace `Companies` within the original list?

Comment: Do you have any decrypt function ?

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to mention we already have a `Decrypt()` function available.

Comment: I think you need to decript it *before* you use it in your expression.

Comment: If you didn't have EF, and you used SQL, how would you do it? If the answer is "it's not possible", it's still not possible with EF-generated SQL. You'd need to load all the companies, have the figure out which contain the search text, and create a query that uses those companies' contacts.

Comment: I have a `MetadataType` as a partial class of `Company` with a property called `DisplayName` that decrypts the `Name` property, however LINQ is telling me the specified type member `DisplayName` is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: It looks like the answer got deleted that had a good idea of encrypting your search text before searching. This should be a viable solution if your encrypt/decrypt is not dependent on a company specific seed.

Comment: it was deleted, because author realised it wouldnt  work :-)

Comment: @TyCobb Well the `searchText` itself doesn't need to be decrypted. It's the `Companies.Name` data that's encrypted.

Comment: personally i expect that you will be forced to do a full table scan especially since it is a contains pattern. I will watch in case EF provider can do more than i know. Instant tick if it can because I expect it cant.

Comment: I understand that, but in your example, that is the only thing you are searching on. No clue how many companies you are working with, but perhaps you should cache your Company list with decrypted names and do your search against your cache first. Any results you find there should then be passed into your LINQ query with the encrypted names. It's the only way I see this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a stored procedure to perform the search:

```
create procedure SearchCompanies @searchText nvarchar(100)
as begin
    select * from Companies c  -- Implement your logic here...
    where dbo.Decrypt(c.Name) like @searchText
end
```

Then, add your stored procedure as a function import to the data context and get your data:

```
using(var dataContext = new DataContext())
{
    return dataContext.SearchCompanies(searchText);
}
```

Comment: i like the answer... using SQL CLR call feature so plus +1.  Still want to see the linq query version :-)